# Change column class if column consists of numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame where I had to convert all variables to the `character` class in order to `bind_rows()`. Now I want to identify and convert the columns that have numbers in them back to class numeric. I have 41 values so I don't want to have to `mutate` each of them separately.

Preferably the tidyverse way.

```
library(dplyr)

data_frame(number_var = as.character(rnorm(1:26)),
           character_var = LETTERS)
```

Comment: `x[] <- lapply(x, function(x) if (any(grepl("\\d", x))) as.numeric(x) else x)`

Comment: @snoram this will also match eg. `"abc123"`. It should be more explicit: `lapply(df, function(x) if (any(grepl("^\\d+$", x))) as.numeric(x) else x)` or even have a threshold: `lapply(df, function(x) if (mean(grepl("^\\d+$", x))>.5) as.numeric(x) else x)`...

Comment: @Tino Right. But taking the instructions literally it should be enough: *convert the columns that have numbers in them*

Comment: @snoram haha, true! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `parse_guess` from `readr`package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df <- data_frame(number_var = as.character(rnorm(1:26)),
           character_var = LETTERS)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(parse_guess) # guess column type for each column
```

Comment: Oeh thanks! Didn't know about the `parse_guess` function, thanks! By the way I changed my example dataframe so you can remove your `mutate_all(as.character) %>%` line.

Comment: OK - removed it.

Comment: @Tdebeus consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.